# Why do JS Promise A+ create/fulfill/reject not part of the spec?

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred, q, rsvp.js

http://promisesaplus.com/

> Finally, the core Promises/A+ specification does not deal with how to
>   create, fulfill, or reject promises, choosing instead to focus on
>   providing an interoperable then method. Future work in companion
>   specifications may touch on these subjects.

As a functional developer, I usually deal with monads and operators like `point` `bind` `map` or `flatMap` to chain calls that are wrapped inside some monad box.

According to this question [Js Deferred/Promise/Future compared to functional languages like Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724883/js-deferred-promise-future-compared-to-functional-languages-like-scala), the `map` and `flatMap` operators seems to be melted together under `then` in the js spec, probably because it would not make so much sense to provide both in a dynamically typed language like Js (?) and it is more convenient to use and remember a single operator.

---

So far so good, there's a `then` operator ([that doesn't seem to always be properly implemented](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/))

But why do the promise create / fulfill / reject is not part of the spec?
It's like just having an half a monad :(
[It seems I'm not the only one to complain](https://twitter.com/puffnfresh/status/321353127666282496)

Typically, my problem is:

- I want to create a JS library
- I want to expose a promise-based API
- I want the client to choose the promise implementation he wants to use

Now what am I supposed to do?

I can create promises in my library like

```
Q.fcall(function () {
    return 10;
})
```

Ok cool, I just coupled my library to Q :(

So, is there any solution to this problem? 
How a library author is supposed to create the promises he exposes to the API without coupling to the implementation?

Is there some license-free minimum viable promise A+ library that we can embed in our libraries or something?

What are the reasons behind this spec choice?

Comment: There is a spec (the promise constructor spec) it's just a different spec. Promises/A+ exists for interop between libraries, not for actual promise implementations to be built just of. All libraries de-facto provide a way to create Promises and Bluebird even lets you promisify whole async APIs with one line of code.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Comment: Also the point of Promises/A+ is that when you wrote a function in your library (like your Q example) other libraries can still consume it because the semantics of how it gets continued are very well defined.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that's true but your client is still forced to add Q while another promise library may already be available/used

Comment: Oh, so the concern is file size? You might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the reasons behind this spec choice?

As Ben points out in the comments, the idea of the Promises/A+ specification is not to provide some sort of library API. It's to provide a minimum interoperable set of primitives so that anyone who *consumes* a promise can depend on it having a uniform interface. This is especially important for cross-library interop e.g. at the seams of different components of an application, where different promise libraries may be in use internally. Specifying the full API for a promise library isn't really necessary to meet this goal.

> Is there some license-free minimum viable promise A+ library that we can embed in our libraries or something?

There are [many Promises/A+ implementations](http://promisesaplus.com/implementations). I don't think any of them are license-free, which is a good thing, because then they'd be by default all rights reserved by their authors. Most (all?) of them are open-source licensed, though, which should be fine.

> How a library author is supposed to create the promises he exposes to the API without coupling to the implementation?

I literally do not understand how this would be possible. If you rephrase this question, you are asking, "how do I create a promise, without using a promise implementation?" That's just plain not possible.

> - I want to expose a promise-based API
> - I want the client to choose the promise implementation he wants to use

This goal, on the other hand, is a different story. If you want to allow people to choose promise implementations, then there are a couple easy options.

First, just return a promise of any implementation; the consumer can convert it to their preferred one using their library's coercion methods. E.g. if your library returns a when promise and I, the consumer, want a Q promise, I can just do `Q(yourLibrary.getPromise())`.

Alternately, you could allow any library that follows the [Promises/A+ constructor proto-spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec/tree/initial-draft). This is largely a de-facto standard by now; most major libraries, including the promises built into ES6, follow that specification. So for example you could allow users to do `yourLibrary.Promise = Q.Promise`, and then inside your library use the assigned promise constructor to create promises.