# Return a non-resolved promise from a promise

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, async-await

`find` is a function that returns a promise that resolves to a value, but also has data on the promise object itself. A practical use case is when `find()` returns a dbQueryObject that can be used elsewhere, whereas `await find()` resolves with databaseResults. eg:

```
function find () {
  var results = new Promise(/* resolves with databaseResults */)
  Object.assign(results, new dbQueryClass)
  return results
}
```

I can wrap `find` with a function to provide helpers like this,

```
function findPage (page) {
 return find().skip(page*20).limit(20)
}
```

and use it like `findPage().select('_id')` to get the query object or `await findPage().select('_id')` to get the resolved value (returns something similar to `find()`).

However, if I wrap `find` with a promise like this,

```
async function findSomething() {
  var someArgs = await promise1()
  if (someArgs) return find(someArgs)
  return find()
}
```

How do I get the value of `find()` itself outside of `findSomething`? I need `promise1` to resolve, but I need `find()` to not resolve. `find()` is a plain object AND a thenable, depending on if you resolve it or not, but resolving `findSomething()` will automatically resolve the returned value. How do I return it such that it doesn't resolve?

My constraint is that I cannot modify the library that provides `find()` to not return a thenable object.

Comment: I don't understand how `Promise.resolve` can execute a query. If it is passed a thenable, then it is essentially a no-op. Anyway, what is your question exactly?

Comment: my question is, how do I not resolve this thenable but do resolve the thenables before this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what would "usually" be an antipattern here. You can `return` or `await` any promise, thenable or plain value in an `async` function, just as you can `Promise.resolve` them or return them from a `then` callback. There is nothing unusual about this, that's just how it is done.

If you want to be explicit about returning a promise, instead of relying on thenable assimilation, you can always [call `.exec()` on your mongoose query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) and it will get you a "real" promise.

Comment: No it won't give me a real promise, it'll give me the resolved value of the promise.

Comment: @aaronz: That's quite unlikely, as that would mean the query would be synchronous. Are you sure that it's not `await ….exec()` that gives you the fulfillment value?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear + more examples. If I `return mongooseQuery()` within a promise, then awaiting that outer promise will give me the fulfillment value of the mongooseQuery. I'd like to get the promise/object without it being `Promise.resolve()`ed.

Comment: The mongoose query is both sync and async. When called with await/Promise.resolve, it returns the fulfillment value. When called synchronously, it returns a Query object (which can be used elsewhere for chaining).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit, it's clear now what your problem is. Unfortunately, [it's impossible to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572). The best thing you'll get is setting `.then` to `null` so that you don't have a thenable any more. But still, a promise for a Query object looks a bit weird to me, you'd have to call `await (await findSomething()).select('id')` or so. Is that really necessary, is it the optimal API?

Answer (score 1):

As stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22724984/704894, it's impossible to have `Promise<Promise<value>>` because when you return a Promise inside `.then` handler, it gets automatically resolved (unwrapped).

You'd have to use `Promise<Wrapper<Promise>>` to bypass this limitation.

*Sidenote for functional programming folks: `.then` is both `map` and `flatMap` in Haskell terms.*